# Solr, find documents where field has any of the values

Tags: solr

I want to search similar to the IN operator in mysql on Solr 4.5.1

I would expect the following to work

```
fk_brand:(1615 928 1457 9 820 1349 414 811 1272)
```

but it didn't. Wondering there could be something wrong with my data I tried

```
fk_brand:(1615)
```

which worked! Any ideas what has changed there?

my original query (doesn't work is)

```
/select?q=*%3A*&fq=date_expires%3A%5BNOW+TO+*%5D&fq=fk_brand%3A(1615+928+1457+9+820+1349+414+811+1272)&sort=computed_ranking+DESC&rows=20&wt=json&indent=true&group=true&group.field=fk_brand&group.limit=3
```

ok, I found out why it doesn't work. This is the debug of the query. It uses the AND operator where I would expect it to use the OR.

```
parsed_filter_queries": [
  "date_expires:[2013-12-09T16:11:38.875Z TO *]",
  "+fk_brand:1615 +fk_brand:928 +fk_brand:1457 +fk_brand:9 +fk_brand:820 +fk_brand:1349 +fk_brand:414 +fk_brand:811 +fk_brand:1272"
```

My default operator is defined as AND. Could it be that it uses the operator defined as default? In any case, how can I make this happen to get the desired result?

Changing my default operator in schema.xml to OR it worked as expected. However, if I would like to keep the default operator to AND, how could I pin point to the query parser/builder that he should use there the OR operator?

Nailed it :D
In case anyone else faces similar problem the answer is

```
fk_brand:(1615 OR 928 OR 1457 OR 9 OR 820 OR 1349 OR 414 OR 811 OR 1272)
```

using the OR operator instead of space (which is identified as the DEFAULT OPERATOR since the DEFAULT SEPARATOR is space).

Comment: Yes, all of your observation is correct!

Comment: you could also set `q.op` for you query. Have a look at [Solr Standard Query Parser](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser)